# No instance for (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector Double) when using Numeric.FFT

Tags: haskell, vector, typeerror

**EDIT: Solution**: The solution to the problem was to specify the correct vector library in a .cabal file. The tell-tale sign (kindly pointed out by @Daniel below) was that the exact **version** of the vector was referenced in the error message. Indeed my file was building against vector-0.10.something while vector-fftw was compiled against vector-0.9.1.

---

I am trying to use the fftw-vector library but am stuck with this type error:

```
-- test.hs
import qualified Numeric.FFT.Vector.Invertible as FFTI
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

z = FFTI.run FFTI.dct1 U.empty

main = putStrLn "Won't compile"
```

This is the error message:

```
No instance for (vector-0.9.1:Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
                   U.Vector Double)
  arising from a use of `FFTI.run'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (vector-0.9.1:Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector U.Vector Double)
In the expression: FFTI.run FFTI.dct1 U.empty
In an equation for `z': z = FFTI.run FFTI.dct1 U.empty
```

but as far as I can tell there is actually an instance of Data.Vector.Gener.Base.Vector for Data.Vector.Unboxed Double [(Link)](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#t%3aVector) (guess I am wrong).

This is with ghc-7.6.1, [vector-0.9.1](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html) and [vector-fftw](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-fftw/0.1.2/doc/html/Numeric-FFT-Vector-Invertible.html).

(I had to make two tiny changes to vector-fftw so it compiles with base 4.6 and ghc-7.6.1, but that should be unrelated ...)

thank you

EDIT:

two changes I made to vector-fftw:

```
--- a/Numeric/FFT/Vector/Base.hsc
+++ b/Numeric/FFT/Vector/Base.hsc
@@ -34,10 +34,11 @@ import Control.Monad.Primitive (RealWorld,PrimMonad(..),
 import Control.Monad(forM_)
 import Foreign (Storable(..), Ptr, unsafePerformIO, FunPtr,
                 ForeignPtr, withForeignPtr, newForeignPtr)
-import Foreign.C (CInt, CUInt)
+-- import Foreign.C (CInt, CUInt)
 import Data.Bits ( (.&.) )
 import Data.Complex(Complex(..))
 import Foreign.Storable.Complex()
+import Foreign.C.Types



diff --git a/vector-fftw.cabal b/vector-fftw.cabal
index 5ca7c46..0436834 100644
--- a/vector-fftw.cabal
+++ b/vector-fftw.cabal
@@ -40,7 +40,7 @@ Library
   Other-modules:
         Numeric.FFT.Vector.Base

-  Build-depends: base>=4.3 && < 4.6, vector==0.9.*, primitive==0.4.*,
+  Build-depends: base>=4.3 && < 4.7, vector==0.9.*, primitive>=0.4 && < 0.6,
                  storable-complex==0.2.*
```

Comment: It does compile with ghc-7.4.1, hmmm... are you shure those changes you made to vector-fftw are unrelated? What are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the error message specifies the specific version of the package that defines the class an instance is missing for:

```
No instance for (vector-0.9.1:Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
                   U.Vector Double)
```

That usually means that one of the used packages was compiled against a different version than the one currently used in the project.

I don't see how exactly this would arise, but check for broken packages with `ghc-pkg check`, and verify that your packages have the correct ids with `ghc-pkg describe vector` and `ghc-pkg describe vector-fftw`, possibly `vector` was rebuilt after building `vector-fftw`. and the package hashes do not match.

Comment: The problem was that I hadn't realized that I also had vector-0.10.something installed. specifying the dependencies in a cabal file correctly resolved the problem. Thanks for your answer, it put me on the right track...